# Is it possible to use Apollo Federation with GraphQL Nexus and Nexus Prisma?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, prisma, apollo-federation

We want to use **Nexus** and **Nexus Prisma** but are also planning on using **Apollo Federation** in the near future.

I saw an open issue that Nexus doesn't support Apollo Federation out of the box:

[Apollo Federation support #148](https://github.com/prisma/nexus/issues/148)

But is it possible to use them together (even in a less elegant way)?

Comment: FWIW, there's a [PR open](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/3018) to allow `buildFederatedSchema` to just decorate an existing GraphQLSchema. This would make federation compatible with a number of tools, including nexus.